How to close all Forms containing a given string in their Caption?
I want to close all forms containing a ClientID string in their caption.
procedure CloseFormsWithClientID(const ClientID: string);
var
  I: Integer;
  Form: TForm;
begin
  // check if client ID is not empty
  if ClientID <> '' then
  begin
    for I := Application.Forms.Count - 1 downto 0 do
    begin
      Form := Application.Forms[I];
      // check if form contains ClientID
      if Pos(ClientID, Form.Caption) > 0 then
      begin
        // close forms
        Form.Close;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

But Application.Forms is an undeclared identifier.
What can I do?

Where is this code located? Where is the rest of the unit it's in? What's in the uses clause of that unit? Please provide a [mre] that demonstrates the issue. This code has no context.

And how did you conclude to use Application.Forms to begin with? Just guesswork? Copied from somewhere?

Are these forms from the running program that has to do this or from other programs running in the (which?)OS?

The Application object does not have a Forms property. You need to use the Screen.Forms property instead.
